# Ordering MySQL results by IN sequence?

Tags: sql, mysql

When I select a set of rows from a table using IN, e.g.

```
SELECT x.y, x.z FROM x WHERE x.id IN (23, 55, 44, 12)
```

is there an SQL trick to get them back in the order given in the IN set?

So in the example, assuming x has rows with ids 23, 55, 44 and 12, those four rows would be returned in that order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT x.y, x.z FROM x WHERE x.id IN (23, 55, 44, 12)
ORDER BY FIELD (x.id, 23, 55, 44, 12)
```

Comment: Is ORDER BY FIELD supported in MySQL 5.0? A: Yes it is! I just checked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Ffind-in-set) as:

```
SELECT x.y, x.z FROM x WHERE x.id IN (23, 55, 44, 12)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(x.id,'23, 55, 44, 12');
```

Comment: On the face of it, there's nothing to choose between your answer and Steve's. But which to accept? In a simple test I tried, ORDER BY FIELD was a bit more than twice as fast